# Teamcity 10 where to store versioned settings

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-10, team-city-10.0

Teamcity 10 offers new feature [storing project settings in version control](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control)

What is the best practice to follow in terms of storing these settings?

- Keep it in the same repo where code resides?
- Put it into separate repo?

Comment: This question is quite old, but how did you store it in the end ?

Answer (score 1):

We have put it into separate Git repository called teamcity-settings after having it in repository with some other stuff for continuous integration. The problem with having it together with something else was that it makes too much "noise" in git history, since every TeamCity build configuration update is doing a commit.

So my suggestion - let TeamCity settings live it's own life in version control. :)

Comment: How did it prove to be when storing the settings in a separate repo ? Was it reliable ?